# Images Quality Loss During Upload

Tags: java, android, bitmap

How do i resolve the quality issues which arise when i use this?. (Please note that adding the values on the createScaledBitmap is not an option since it makes upload very slow)

```
private String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap1, 320, 320, true);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

Comment: What is the source of the `Bitmap`? JPEG is for photos, mostly. PNG will give you better results for other sorts of images (icons, line art, etc.).

Comment: The source is from user phones. Could be JPEG or PNG

Comment: Then perhaps you should track whether the input is JPEG or PNG and convert the image back into that format, rather than forcing everything to be JPEG. Beyond that, `createScaledBitmap()` is not necessarily going to be using a good algorithm for converting arbitrary types of images. You might want to find some library for image scaling that offers more options.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare which images scaling library do you reccomend?

Comment: I have not had a need for one in an Android app, so I cannot make a specific recommendation. The Android Arsenal [image processing](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/47?sort=created) and [native image processing](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/63?sort=created) categories will contain some options (along with other libraries for image processing).